# Get class name of the calling class

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, testng, test-strategy

I needed to get a `class name` from my calling class. I will not make too much confusion.

I have 3 classes.

```
Class A{ //do something } 

Class B extends Class A 
{ 
     @Test(dataProvider = "dp" , dataProviderClass = C.class)
     public void methodone(String name)
     {
       //do something
     }
} 


Class C extends Class A 
{
    @DataProvider(name="dp")
    public Object[][] getData(Method m) {
        String sheetName = m.getName();
        System.out.println("---"+sheetName); }
}
```

In the `Class C`, I need the name of the calling class to be printed.

But for now it is printing the name of the calling method, which is `methodone` of `class B`. But I need as `class B` to be printed.

Could some one help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will help you

```
public class Dummy {
    @DataProvider(name="dp")
    public Object[][] getData(Method m) {
        //this will print respective class name
        System.out.println(m.getDeclaringClass());
        return new Object[][] {{"name"}};
    }
}
```

Will print the class name as shown in image below
[image]

You can get only the class name by applying the `split` feature over the extracted string

Using `split` function to get the class name

```
@DataProvider(name="dp")
    public Object[][] getData(Method m) {
        String classname=m.getDeclaringClass().toString().split(" ")[1];
        System.out.println(classname.split("\\.")[classname.split("\\.").length-1]);
        return new Object[][] {{"Testing is awesome"}};
    }
```

Using inbuilt function to get the class name

```
@DataProvider(name="dp")
    public Object[][] getData(Method m) {
        String classname=m.getDeclaringClass().getSimpleName();
        System.out.println(classname);
        return new Object[][] {{"Testing is awesome"}};
    }
```

Comment: Hi Mohamed, thanks it worked. But Apologies, i forgot to tell you all these classes are under a package - eg: package 1. so for the first time i got as "**class package1.Class B**". i used the following as well - splitting by a space gave me - package1.Class B. Then i did by a dot and then by "//." , nothing worked. sorry for the trouble. I needed just the "ClassB" in the example.

Comment: You should use \\  instead of  // .Kindly refer my updated answer and accept it if it helped you

Comment: Thank you very much sir. it worked. Thanks a lot. i need 15 points to upvote your answer.so once i get it , i am going to upvote your answer. Take care.

Comment: You can just use `..getDeclaringClass().getSimpleName()` instead of splitting everything..

Comment: You can accept it by clicking on the check mark near the [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86979)

Comment: @AlexeyR. Updated the answer

Comment: @user12730187 accepting the answers will help others to find the solutions more effectively. It also gives you reputation points that makes you obtain more capabilities on the forum.

Comment: Hi Mohammed and Alexey , Apologies . For a brief moment i had forgotten how to accept the answer. i have done it . Many thanks to you both.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the above answer,

If you refer the documentation

https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-dataproviders

```
If you declare your @DataProvider as taking a java.lang.reflect.Method as first parameter,
```

so whatever class methods supported for `java.lang.reflect.Method` class will be supported inside the data provider, you can see all the available methods at:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html